# not able to set the yesterday date to kendo ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have got problem with setting date to kendo ui date picker, I am successfully able to set the today date by using the following code :

```
  var todayDate = new Date();
  $('#createdonend').data("kendoDatePicker").value(todayDate);
```

I am not able to set the yesterday date by using following code

```
 var todayDate = new Date();
 var yesterdayDate = todayDate.getDate() - 1;
  $('#createdonbegin').data("kendoDatePicker").value(yesterdayDate);
```

for the above function I am getting error like this

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**
in this file 
**/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.all.min.js**

would any one pls help on this one why i am getting this error for setting yesterday date to kendo ui datepicker..

Many thanks In advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Niels said you have to use:

```
yesterdayDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
```

for setting yesterday date **but** you need to have `yesterdayDate` initialized to today's `Date` before setting it to previous day since `setDate` only sets the day of the month.

So, the proposed code is:

```
// Create a "date" object with today's date
var date = new Date();
// Changes the day of the month to previous, this keeps in mind month and year changes
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
// Set the new date
$('#createdonbegin').data("kendoDatePicker").value(date);
```

Running example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/v7UPr/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the following:

```
yesterdayDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
```

`getDate` will get the number of days in the month, not a `Date` object.

> The value returned by getDate is an integer between 1 and 31.

Sources:

1. [getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

Comment: Sorry I am getting error at these lines `yesterdayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 1);
        alert(yesterdayDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1));                
 $('#createdonbegin').data("kendoDatePicker").value(yesterdayDate);`

Comment: Is your variable  yesterdayDate over here is Date Object?